# MouseLeave Event Doesn't Trigger After a Click?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox, mouseevent, mouseover

I have a simple issue in my Windows Form. I have a listbox that is acting as a log for some serial data I have input, and would like to be able to use the scroll wheel to move thru it. In order to do this, I have a variable, hoverList, set to 0 initially, which becomes 1 inside the MouseEnter event for the listbox. Then for the MouseWheel event, I increase or decrease the selected index in the listbox, but only if hoverList is 1. I expect that when the mouse leaves the area above the listbox, the MouseLeave event will fire, which sets hoverList to 0 and stops allowing "scrolling". This works fine, until I click in the listbox; I can still scroll just fine, but now I can scroll the listbox everywhere on my screen. It seems that clicking inside the listbox doesn't allow the MouseLeave event to ever trigger. Is this the case? And if so, is there a workaround that avoids this problem? Code for the 3 events is shown below

```
Private Sub LstSerialData_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstSerialData.MouseLeave
    hoverList = 0
End Sub

Private Sub LstSerialData_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstSerialData.MouseEnter
    hoverList = 1
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseWheel
    If hoverList Then
        If e.Delta > 0 Then
            If lstSerialData.SelectedIndex > 10 Then
                lstSerialData.SelectedIndex -= 10
            Else
                lstSerialData.SelectedIndex = 0
            End If
        Else
            If lstSerialData.SelectedIndex < lstSerialData.Items.Count - 10 Then
                lstSerialData.SelectedIndex += 10
            Else
                lstSerialData.SelectedIndex = lstSerialData.Items.Count - 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use numbers to represent Boolean values without good reason.  Based on what you have said, `hoverList` should be type `Boolean` and have values `True` and `False`, not 1 and 0.  Also, you really ought to use descriptive names for variables.  `hoverList` isn't really descriptive.  Without an explanation, no one is going to know what that means.  A variable name like `isMouseOverListBox` or the like needs no further explanation.  In these days of IDEs and Intellisense, it's false economy to use short, cryptic variables names.

Comment: You don't need to ask us whether it's the case that `MouseLeave` is not raised after a click.  That's what the debugger is for.  You should always have already debugged your code before posting here.  Debugging does mean just running the code.  It means setting breakpoints, stepping through the code and examining state at appropriate points.  If you put a breakpoint on that `MouseLeave` event handler and it doesn't get hit then the event is not being raised.

Comment: With regards to my first comment about using a `Boolean` variable, the fact that you can use numbers in the way you have indicates that you have `Option Strict Off`, which is bad in itself.  It is, unfortunately, the default setting but everyone should change that ASAP.  You should set `Option Strict On` in the project properties and also in the IDE options, so it is the default for future projects.

Comment: I just tested your code in VS 2017 and I didn't see the behaviour you describe.  I did as I suggested and saw the breakpoint hit whether I clicked an item or not.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you for all of the information, I have taken your advice and changed the variable type to 'Boolean', as well as made 'Option Strict On'. I also added a breakpoint at the 'MouseLeave' event and noticed that it does fire every time. The value is 'False' as soon as the mouse leaves the area over the listbox, however I still have the issue where after I click in the box, I can scroll it from anywhere, even though the variable is false and the "scrolling" action only occurs inside an 'If' statement checking for the hover variable to be true. Why might this be?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the problem. When clicking in the listbox,it becomes the selected control; since it has a scrollbar, I am actually allowed to use the scroll wheel to scroll thru it. Moving the cursor off of the listbox disables *my* built in scroll, but doesn't deselect the listbox, meaning I can still scroll thru it. I edited my `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events to select and deselect the listbox respectively. This means that as soon as my cursor leaves the listbox, regardless of whether or not I have clicked inside it, it is deselected and will no longer let me scroll thru it. It also means my ghetto workaround to allow scrolling was no longer needed.